# Python Parse text

Tags: python

Here is a text, I need to parse;

```
JAVA_OPTS=blablalba
lbalbalba

1. main1:

     aelo1 2020-06-15 11 4422
     sddg2 2020-06-12 19 422

2. main2:

     fdata3 2020-06-15 11 4422
     gcontent4 2020-06-12 19 422

3. main3:

     hxvnt5 2020-06-15 11 4422
     vcfdet6 2020-06-12 19 422
```

I need to only parse the numbered bullet point, until next bullet point. and find the 4 th column greater than 1000 and older than 12 hours (2nd column date time) then send the details in email. I tried parsing via re library in python, but cannot achieve it.

So the expected output is;

```
    1. main1:

         aelo1 2020-06-15 11 4422

    2. main2:

         fdata3 2020-06-15 11 4422

    3. main3:

         hxvnt5 2020-06-15 11 4422
```

is it possible via bash or python ?

Comment: What do you mean "older than 12h"?

Comment: The "older than 12 hours" requirement needs clarification - do you want to keep the rows with 3rd column values > 12 or ignore them? 
Also, sharing what you have tried will help others help you.

Comment: Add parse to you post tag

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex which you can use to match (I am not sure about 12 hours).

```
\d+\.\s\S+\s+\S+\s[0-9-]+\s\d+\s[1-9][0-9]{3,}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution for you

```py
def parsing(text):
    if text.strip() == '':
        return ''
    lines = text.split('\n')
    buffer = ''
    for line in lines:
        t = line.strip()
        if t == '' or t[0] in '0123456789':
            buffer += line + '\n'
        else:
            lst = t.split()
            if len(lst) >= 4:
                if (len(lst[1].split('-'))==3 and int(lst[2]) <= 12 and
                        int(lst[3]) > 1000):
                    buffer += line + '\n'
    return buffer.strip()

print(parsing(text))
```

Comment: That's why requested to provide more information about their requirements and situations. Updated.

Comment: Updated the expected output for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Can use [TTP](https://ttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation.html) to parse/filter it in one template:

```
from ttp import ttp
import pprint

data = """
JAVA_OPTS=blablalba
lbalbalba

1. main1:

     aelo1 2020-06-15 11 4001
     sddg2 2020-06-12 19 422

2. main2:

     fdata3 2020-06-16 11 4422
     gcontent4 2020-06-12 19 422

3. main3:

     hxvnt5 2020-06-17 11 4002
     vcfdet6 2020-06-12 19 422
"""
    
template = """
<group contains="value">
1. main1: {{ _start_ }}
     {{ ignore }} {{ date }} {{ hour | lessthan("12") }} {{ value | greaterthan("4000") }}
</group>     
"""
    
parser = ttp(data, template)
parser.parse()
res = parser.result()
pprint.pprint(res)

# prints:
# [[[{'date': '2020-06-15', 'hour': '11', 'value': '4001'},
#    {'date': '2020-06-16', 'hour': '11', 'value': '4422'},
#    {'date': '2020-06-17', 'hour': '11', 'value': '4002'}]]]
```

Can test templates online [here](http://%20http://textfsm.nornir.tech/) if you'd like.

Disclaimer: I am the author of TTP.

Edit: after parsing can further post-process results to compose email report or whatever the end result must look like.