# Python make a list of ints and floats on the same line

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, integer

I am building a python program that requires getting the integer and float values on the same line and storing it as a variable as well as filtering out everything that is not 6 characters long. For example:

```
'TEST
3E 37 2810
173819 TEST 12.45
173829 TEST 3.74
271838 TEST 3.54
373828 TEST 2.37
2717 TEST 4.31
TEST 2.99'
```

I would like for the program to only extract these values: `[173819, 1.45], [173829, 3.74], [271838, 3.54], [373828, 2.37]` and add them to a list.

I have tried using this code for getting the values that are 5-7 characters in length but this does not get the float values for the same line and adding them to the list:

```
numbers = [int(s) for s in Text.split() if s.isdigit()]
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
                    getvalue = str(numbers[i])
                    length = (len(getvalue))
                    if length == 5:
                        values.append(numbers[i])
                    elif length == 6:
                        values.append(numbers[i])
                    elif length == 7:
                        values.append(numbers[i])
                print(values)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Ideally you should include an attempt at solving the problem in your question. This will improve your skills as a developer and increase the chance you get help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Parse text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62421344/python-parse-text)

Comment: Why do you check for the length being 5-7 characters? The first part of your question kind of implies you interested in lines where the integer has 6 digits, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:
given:

```
inData = 'TEST \n3E 37 2810\n173819 TEST 12.45\n173829 TEST 3.74\n271838 TEST 3.54\n373828 TEST 2.37\n2717 TEST 4.31\nTEST 2.99'
```

Then:

```
inlines = inData.split('\n')
for l in inlines:
    j = l.split(' ')
    if len(j) >= 3 and and len(j[0])>= 6:
        print(f"Integer: {int(j[0])}\tFloat: {float(j[2])}")
```

Yields:

```
Integer: 173819 Float: 12.45
Integer: 173829 Float: 3.74
Integer: 271838 Float: 3.54
Integer: 373828 Float: 2.37
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It really helped me a lot with this issue!

Comment: Would there be a way to make these value into a dictionary automatically?

Comment: Sure what do you want to use as the key? and what is the value

Comment: Does this code work for multi line strings with no \n also?

Comment: sure just skip the step where you are splitting the input based on '\n'.

Comment: When using something such as 373828 3x EGGS 3.99 would there be a way to filter out the middle text (EGGS) and (3x) regardless of what the text is or the length? Such as 738283 2x THIS IS AN ITEM 3.99 to 738283, 3.99.

Comment: How would you define the separation between what you want and what you don't want?  (i.e. number of characters from start or number of words from the start, and number of characters/words from the end, special text delimiter, other)

Comment: Just anything that is not a 6 digit integer or a float

Comment: Just edited my solution to satisfy your need.